# Choose 2 elements from 1D array to multidimensional array

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array

I am currently doing some feature selection for my project and I have met some problem with creating an array of this sort.

I have an array of 115 rows and 1 column.

```
1
2
...
115
```

I would like to create a 2D array that takes in the first value and all the other values as the 2nd column, while not repeating any previous pair of value`(1 2) is the same as (2 1)`

```
1 2
1 3
...
1 115
2 3
2 4
...
114 115
```

My current code is not creating the array as intended. test is the array of 115 rows. test1 is the new array I want to create.

```
for i=1:115
    for j=i:115
        if (i == j)
            j=j+1;
        else
            test1(i,j)=test(j);
        end
    end
end
```

Any advice will be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `nchoosek`:

```
nchoosek(1:115,2)
```

Comment: Wow! That is a super neat function! Thank for the fast reply!